# Auto scoll a page when an image is at the top of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok I have a page with stacked `div`'s and anchors which use a jquery slide slide down. When the bottom of a stacked div reaches the top of the screen I want the jquery to automatically scroll to the next div, which may be 1000px south. 
 How can i do this in javascript?

my idea is to put an image the bottom of the div and somehow check the screen to see if the image is in the top half of the monitor which would call a function to scroll to the next anchor..

Is this possible?

[image: img of what i need]

Comment: I think http://api.jquery.com/category/offset/ should do the trick quite easily

Comment: thx for the reply.. checking it out.. will report back! offset is looking promising..

Comment: no problem, you could use it together with `var wHeight = $(window).height()/2;` to get the center of the window
and when offset is lower then that
`if($('img').offset() < wHeight) do something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var wHeight =$(window).height()/2;  
$(window).scroll(function(){   

    var imgOff = $('#two').offset().top-$(window).scrollTop();

    if(imgOff<wHeight){    
        alert('Kill BILL!');    
    }    
});
```

havent tried this out but it should work
Edit: this works try it here
http://jsfiddle.net/BG2Cz/
P.S. Be warned it will spam alerts once u pass the middle

Comment: i set the image with the ID= SKIP and i replaced `'img'` to `'#SKIP'` but im not getting the alert..

Comment: @FabioAnselmo give me a sec ill check

Comment: yep it works.. looks like the key was `.top-$(window).scrollTop();
`   So how do you suggest i make it go to the next div.. `$("a.anchorLink").anchorAnimate()` ?

Comment: `$(window).scroll('#name_next_div');` after the if statement. is not working.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the if statment i made is the center of the screen, you should probably remove the divided by 2 for your script at line 1 on my sample

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15693/discussion-between-breezer-and-fabio-anselmo)